# How to use daterangepicker inside a ng-repeat directive in angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularJS, i don't know how to use daterangepicker inside the ng-repeat directive.

Please help me regarding this topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are tons of UI plugin are called daterangepicker , which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this example helps you, 
NOTE: download ngBehavior from [ngBehavior](https://github.com/maherAshori/ngBehavior)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="date in dates">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="datePicker" ng-date-picker min-date="{{date.from}}" max-date="{{date.to}}" placeholder="from {{date.from}}, to {{date.to}}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <!--download from https://github.com/maherAshori/ngBehavior -->
  <script src="/Scripts/ngBehavior/ngBehavior.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module("app", ["ngBehavior"]);
    angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.dates = [{
        from: "2015/12/16",
        to: "2015/12/20"
      }, {
        from: "2016/01/01",
        to: "2016/01/15"
      }, {
        from: "2016/05/10",
        to: "2016/06/25"
      }];
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i need daterangepicker model dialog box should be popup and user should able to select to and from date from that popup.   Thanks in advance